# Excel: how to create a group based on one of the items in the list

Tags: microsoft-excel

My data
A1: john. B1: ordinary
A2: john. B2: overtime
A3: jonh. B3: penalty

If overtime exists in any of the cells in B1:B3 then I want to tag all of the items as overtime
Answer should be:

C1: overtime
C2: overtime
C3: overtime

How to write the formula in cell C?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Formula for `C1`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,"overtime")>0,"overtime","")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!This did it.

Comment: I missed this was COUNTIFS and not just COUNTIF. Well done @Engineer toast!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired result by making use of `VLOOKUP`. I have created a sample data as you've provided in the question:

[image]

Now, if any of the the data in B1:B3 range corresponds to the text `overtime`, you needed to display all the corresponding results at C1:C3 as `overtime`. For that, I have used to `VLOOKUP` formula which looks up for that particular text string and displays the required result as follows:

`=IF(VLOOKUP($B$2,$B$1:$B$3,1,FALSE)="overtime","overtime","Not overtime")`

After entering this formula in the C1 cell and hitting enter, the result will be shown as overtime. Drag it down and all the cells will show the same results:

[image]

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The countifs solution below is much easier, though I leave this here in case you need to do something else than count in the grouping.

Assuming your data looks like this:

```
john   ord
john   overtime
sally  ord
sally  penalty
jack   ord
jack   ord
jack   penalty
```

I.e. the groups vary in length and don't always have overtime in there.

In this case we'll use INDEX(...):INDEX(...) to return a range in column B that all have the same value in A. Lets define the data in col A as data1 and the data in col B as data2. Then in C2:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(grouprange,"overtime")>1,"overtime","")
```

where grouprange is

```
=INDEX(data2,MATCH(A2,data1,0)):INDEX(data2,MATCH(A2,data1,0)+COUNTIF(data1,A2)-1)
```

If you want to be fancy, actually define grouprange as a named range in Excel. Put your cursor in C2, click Formulas > Define Name, and add the formula above to the "refers to" textbox. Now, grouprange is known as a dynamic named range (i.e. a named range that changes based on the location of the cell it is used in).

Comment: To understand how grouprange is defined, here it is in abstract form (relative to C2) = INDEX(data2, first occurrence of A2 in data1):INDEX(data2, first occurrence of A2 in data1 + number of occurrences of A2 in data1 - 1)

Comment: Thanks for the tips!!!